# sort by one column within groups of another without changing positions of grouping column

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

consider the `df`

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(A=list('babbaa'), B=list('zxyxzy')))
df
```

[image]

I want to sort `B` with groups defined by `A`.  But I don't want the positions of `A` to change.

If I try:

```
df.groupby('A', sort=False) \
    .apply(pd.DataFrame.sort_values, by='B') \
    .reset_index(drop=True)
```

[image]

You'll notice that `A` is grouped together.  I wanted this:

[image]

Comment: Would there be any duplicated pairs, say for eg: *(a,x)* repeated more than once in the actual data?

Comment: @NickilMaveli let's say no

Comment: Well, I've got a solution which can handle even dups. But haven't tested it thoroughly enough. I'll write it anyways.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your contrived example:

Sort *w.r.t* both A and B and let A take on the index. Later, reset the index to make a reference `DF`.

```
A = df.sort_values(['A', 'B']).set_index('A').reset_index()
```

Next, set A as the index along with the normal integer index by using `append`. Sort the index(which belongs to A). Now reset the index again.

```
B = df.set_index('A', append=True).sort_index(level=1).reset_index(level=1)
```

Let A take on B's index. Sort the obtained index axis.

```
A.index = B.index
A.sort_index()
```

[image]

Comment: very creative :-)

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I've come up with

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(A=list('babbaa'), B=list('zxyxzy')))

A, B = df.A.values, df.B.values
```

Use [`np.unique`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html) inverse (index values in all their relative positions).

```
u, iv = np.unique(A, return_inverse=True)
```

Use inverse and broadcasting to create a row for every group, where each row is a boolean mask for that group.

```
is_ = np.arange(len(u))[:, None] == iv
```

Loop over rows and reassign a position tracking array `i` with updated values.

```
i = np.arange(len(df))
for r in is_:
    i[r] = i[r][df.B.values[r].argsort()]
```

Use new position values

```
df.iloc[i]
```

[image]

---

At the moment, I can't figure out how to get rid of that loop.